# simple C program, printf not printing

Tags: c, while-loop, printf

I'm new here , asking questions at least. Always have been able to find good answers here. Trying to get back into programming and relearning C but ran into weird issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
    ++nc;
    printf("%ld \n", nc);
}
```

When I run it, after I type in any amount of characters and hit enter, it does not print the value of nc.
After hitting enter, I can start typing again and well, same story. Really can't see what could be wrong. The only way it works is if I place both ++nc and the printf within brackets. But then when I hit enter, it gives the value 1-to-nc, which is not what I want. I just want nc.
Needless to say the type is not the issue either.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What makes you think EOF has anything to do with ENTER?

Comment: How do I get EOF?, hitting Control and D only gives me ^D. which does nothing

Comment: What OS are you using? Does Control-D after ENTER work as EOF?

Comment: Actually I just found Ctrl-Z seems to work as EOF on my system.
I'm running windows 7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type `Ctrl-D` in your terminal to send `EOF`. You may want

```
while (getchar() != '\n')
```

instead if you want it to work with enter.

Comment: That's an infinite loop if getchar returns EOF.

Comment: @Jens I know I was saying if he wanted it to work with pressing the enter key instead of EOF.

Comment: But how hard is it to fix this bug and make the program deal with real world input, *which always has an EOF eventually*?

Answer (score 3):

You need to hit Ctrl-D to get a EOF.

Comment: Control d only seems to give me ^D

Comment: found a different solution, but could you explain the ^D pls 
thanks

Comment: I Figured it out, its Ctrl-Z on my system

Answer (score 1):

try

> while(getchar() != '\n')
>       nc++;

Edit : Assuming the input taken from console, '\n' suffices.

Comment: That's an infinite loop if getchar returns EOF.

Comment: @Jens: as I am taking input manually from console, i can stop the program by hitting enter.

Comment: It's a bug nonetheless. What if someone runs the program with stdin redirected from a file? What if that file is empty?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get nc printed inside the loop, you should include the print statement in the loop like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF) {
    ++nc;
    printf("%ld \n", nc);
    }
}
```

That prints nc once for each character after hitting [enter], maybe not what you want.

If you want to print nc once per line use scanf and do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    char buf[128];
    while (scanf("%s",&buf) > 0) {
      int len = strlen(buf);
      nc += len;
      printf("%ld \n", nc);
    } 
}
```